# SQL updating a table selecting from another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sum

To simplify a bit, I have a `product` table:

```
PRODUCT
---
id
type (FK)
```

And the corresponing 1:1 `type` table (`product.type -> type.id`):

```
TYPE
---
id
weight
```

Then I have a `packaging` table.

```
PACKAGING
---
id
total_weight
```

A packaging can contain one ore more products. The `packaging.total_weight` is a convenience field that stores the SUM of all the weights of the products it contains.

The n*m `packaging*products` relationship is realized by the `nm_packaging_product` table:

```
NM_PACKAGING_PRODUCT
---
packaging_id (PK, FK)
product_id (PK, FK)
```

Now, someone can change the weight of a product. When this happens, I want to update the `packaging.total_weight` computing the new weight. All I know is the `@product_id` whose weight has changed.

I'd like to `UPDATE` with a single SQL. Like:

```
UPDATE
    PACKAGING
SET
    total_weight=???
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT packaging_id FROM NM_PACKAGING_PRODUCT WHERE product_id = @prodotto_id)
```

How?

Comment: What is the SQL platform? UPDATE syntax is different on different platforms.

Comment: MySQL. I'm updating the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
UPDATE
    PACKAGING
SET
    total_weight= (select sum(weight) from TYPE,NM_PACKAGING_PRODUCT, PRODUCT
                   where type.id = product.type and product.id= nm_product.product_id and 
                   nm_packaging_product.packaging_id = packaging.id  )
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT packaging_id FROM NM_PACKAGING_PRODUCT WHERE product_id = @prodotto_id)
```

Comment: Are you sure? I think it will update all the packagings with the same weight.

Comment: Did you try? or just guess?

Comment: packaging.id  represents the record that currently updating, so every packaging will not have same weight

Comment: I guessed, now tried and it doesn't work. Or, it works as expected.

Comment: Is there any error? or updated values are not expected values?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It works perfectly. The good thing was here `nm_packaging_product.packaging_id = packaging.id`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recalculate all the weights and only reset the ones that change:

```
UPDATE PACKAGING p JOIN
       (SELECT packaging_id, SUM(weight) as total_weight
        FROM NM_PACKAGING_PRODUCT pp
        GROUP BY packing_id
       ) ppw
       ON p.packaging_id = ppw.packaging_id    
    SET total_weight = ppw.total_weight
    where p.total_weight <> ppw.total_weight;
```

This will also solve the issue when the same product appears multiple times in a package.

Comment: `SUM(weight)` from `NM_PACKAGING_PRODUCT`? Also, I have a product_id, to avoid selecting everything.

Comment: @vulkanino . . . I would recalculate the entire weight for the packages and reset to the correct value.  Unless you have a lot of data, then doing piecemeal updates can lead to longer term maintenance problems.